# Upgrading only several packages, ou packages from one source

Tags: apt, aptitude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a command to upgrade a package and all its dependencies without upgrading all packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179160/is-there-a-command-to-upgrade-a-package-and-all-its-dependencies-without-upgradi)

we use Deb/apt system to deploy PHP softwares (around 200 + libraries with dependencies). We have a build server, scripts, and a private repository. It's ok and run fine but we want to update ours packages very often, and update Ubuntu packages only when our adminsys have time to handle them.

How can we do? The only solution I see for now is to iterate on package list and do a `apt-get install $packagename`. Not very easy or even resilient.

Another idea?

Comment: Check out the script in  [this page] (http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=51644)  If you can manage to tweak the code a bit it should fit your needs.

Comment: The other question "Is there a command to upgrade a package and all its dependencies without upgrading all packages?" does not answer my need, and I cannot make the given solutions work. So I have no answer for my question.